# Matlab m-file compiled with mcc crashes with java error only if running from Visual Studio

Tags: java, visual-studio-2010, matlab, matlab-deployment, mcc

I have a `CFD` Fortran code that calls a batch file this way:

```
  res = SYSTEM('start matlab.bat')
```

The bat file then runs a deployable Matlab code, a little code to plot some data, with this command:

`start MYmatlabCODE.exe`

When I run my compiled `CFD` code with a double click on the `exe` file, the deployable matlab executable is called and it runs with no problem, both in my machine and in another machine where I copied it. However, when I compile and run my `CFD` code from Intel Visual Studio, the Matlab executable crashes with a Java error right after starting. The log is copied below. Any clue?

I tried to follow instruction [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/10388-matlab-crashes-on-startup-after-segfault-on-last) that are not for a compiled `m` file but it didn't help. thanks.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000777108c5, pid=8064, tid=6156
#
# JRE version: 6.0_17-b04
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (14.3-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ntdll.dll+0x508c5]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00000000008b9000):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_Java, id=6156, stack(0x0000000006cc0000,0x00000000074c0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0xffffffffffffffff

Registers:
EAX=0x00000000074bbe88, EBX=0x0000000000000002, ECX=0x00000000074bbf58, EDX=0x00000000074bbec8
ESP=0x00000000074bbe78, EBP=0x000007fee8d8de90, ESI=0x0000000000000020, EDI=0x0000000000000000
EIP=0x00000000777108c5, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00000000074bbe78)
0x00000000074bbe78:   0000000000000202 00000000776cb219
0x00000000074bbe88:   000007fffffdb000 0000000000000510
0x00000000074bbe98:   0000000078bf7f16 000000000d9c8800
0x00000000074bbea8:   0000000000000002 00000000110759b0
0x00000000074bbeb8:   0000000000000050 00000000110759b0
0x00000000074bbec8:   00000000074c0000 0000000006cc3000
0x00000000074bbed8:   0000000000000002 000000000d9c8800
0x00000000074bbee8:   000000000dc53b60 0000000000000000
0x00000000074bbef8:   00000000074bc0e0 00000000074bc110
0x00000000074bbf08:   00000000089604d7 0000000200000003
0x00000000074bbf18:   000000000dc5d3a0 000000000dbc8c80
0x00000000074bbf28:   00000000074bc730 00000000089da17c
0x00000000074bbf38:   00000000089d9e90 0000000000000000
0x00000000074bbf48:   00000000222399b8 00000000074bc730
0x00000000074bbf58:   00000000074bc700 0000000008996f7a
0x00000000074bbf68:   0000000008996f10 0000000000000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x00000000777108c5)
0x00000000777108b5:   00 00 4c 89 b1 e8 00 00 00 4c 89 b9 f0 00 00 00
0x00000000777108c5:   0f ae 81 00 01 00 00 0f 29 81 a0 01 00 00 0f 29 


Stack: [0x0000000006cc0000,0x00000000074c0000],  sp=0x00000000074bbe78,  free space=8175k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [ntdll.dll+0x508c5]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
v  blob 0x0000000008997039
j  java.util.jar.JarFile.getJarEntry(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/jar/JarEntry;+5
j  sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Lsun/misc/Resource;+48
j  sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Lsun/misc/Resource;+53
j  java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+26
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedExceptionAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;+13
j  java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/lang/Class;+43
j  sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/lang/Class;+41
j  java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;+3
j  java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;+2
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  com.mathworks.services.Prefs.<clinit>()V+74
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  java.lang.Class.forName0(Ljava/lang/String;ZLjava/lang/ClassLoader;)Ljava/lang/Class;+0
j  java.lang.Class.forName(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;+5
j  com.mathworks.util.PostVMInit$StartupClass.init(ZZ)V+28
j  com.mathworks.util.PostVMInit.perform(ZZ)V+31
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x000000000c7a7800 JavaThread "JMI Unnamed Thread" [_thread_in_native, id=8668, stack(0x0000000005fe0000,0x00000000060e0000)]
  0x000000000c7a6000 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10452, stack(0x0000000006110000,0x0000000006190000)]
  0x000000000c7bf800 JavaThread "CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7304, stack(0x000000000cdf0000,0x000000000cef0000)]
  0x000000000c7b9000 JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5564, stack(0x000000000cc90000,0x000000000cd90000)]
  0x000000000c7a5000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9168, stack(0x000000000c120000,0x000000000c1a0000)]
  0x000000000c445000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8800, stack(0x000000000c6c0000,0x000000000c740000)]
  0x000000000c43f000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4592, stack(0x000000000c1b0000,0x000000000c230000)]
=>0x00000000008b9000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_Java, id=6156, stack(0x0000000006cc0000,0x00000000074c0000)]

Other Threads:
  0x000000000c436000 VMThread [stack: 0x000000000c550000,0x000000000c650000] [id=9340]
  0x000000000c7f8800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x000000000cfa0000,0x000000000d0a0000] [id=8492]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 14336K, used 5760K [0x0000000022150000, 0x0000000023150000, 0x0000000025250000)
  eden space 12288K, 46% used [0x0000000022150000,0x00000000226f0370,0x0000000022d50000)
  from space 2048K, 0% used [0x0000000022f50000,0x0000000022f50000,0x0000000023150000)
  to   space 2048K, 0% used [0x0000000022d50000,0x0000000022d50000,0x0000000022f50000)
 PSOldGen        total 49152K, used 0K [0x0000000018e50000, 0x000000001be50000, 0x0000000022150000)
  object space 49152K, 0% used [0x0000000018e50000,0x0000000018e50000,0x000000001be50000)
 PSPermGen       total 32768K, used 3403K [0x0000000010e50000, 0x0000000012e50000, 0x0000000018e50000)
  object space 32768K, 10% used [0x0000000010e50000,0x00000000111a2fa0,0x0000000012e50000)

Dynamic libraries:
0x000000013f9c0000 - 0x000000013fa00000     C:\UNIVERSITY\CENTROmaree\datiPRESSIONEeMAREE\D3D_outputs\2013010200_1_201410231215\readHISTORYfile.exe
0x00000000776c0000 - 0x0000000077869000     C:\windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00000000774a0000 - 0x00000000775bf000     C:\windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x000007fefd840000 - 0x000007fefd8ac000     C:\windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00000000775c0000 - 0x00000000776ba000     C:\windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x000007fefd8b0000 - 0x000007fefd917000     C:\windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x000007feff410000 - 0x000007feff41e000     C:\windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x000007feff070000 - 0x000007feff139000     C:\windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x000007feff370000 - 0x000007feff40f000     C:\windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x000007feff430000 - 0x000007feff50b000     C:\windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x000007fefe7b0000 - 0x000007fefe7cf000     C:\windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x000007feff8a0000 - 0x000007feff9cd000     C:\windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x000000006c0a0000 - 0x000000006c173000     C:\windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_08e61857a83bc251\MSVCP90.dll
0x000000006c1b0000 - 0x000000006c253000     C:\windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_08e61857a83bc251\MSVCR90.dll
0x000007fefd330000 - 0x000007fefd387000     C:\windows\system32\apphelp.dll
0x000007feea830000 - 0x000007feea88a000     C:\windows\AppPatch\AppPatch64\AcLayers.DLL
0x000007fefb570000 - 0x000007fefb5e1000     C:\windows\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
0x000007fefa3b0000 - 0x000007fefa3c8000     C:\windows\system32\MPR.dll
0x000007fee8ae0000 - 0x000007fee8f47000     C:\windows\AppPatch\AppPatch64\AcXtrnal.DLL
0x000007feeedc0000 - 0x000007feeee11000     C:\windows\AppPatch\AppPatch64\AcGenral.DLL
0x000007fefd300000 - 0x000007fefd325000     C:\windows\system32\SspiCli.dll
0x000007fefeac0000 - 0x000007fefeb31000     C:\windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x000007fefee60000 - 0x000007feff063000     C:\windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x000007fefda20000 - 0x000007fefe7a8000     C:\windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x0000000073c80000 - 0x0000000073c83000     C:\windows\system32\sfc.dll
0x000007fefb1f0000 - 0x000007fefb200000     C:\windows\system32\sfc_os.DLL
0x000007fefd510000 - 0x000007fefd52e000     C:\windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x000007fefd4f0000 - 0x000007fefd4ff000     C:\windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x000007fefb7d0000 - 0x000007fefb7e8000     C:\windows\system32\dwmapi.dll
0x000007fefeb40000 - 0x000007fefeb6e000     C:\windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x000007fefe7d0000 - 0x000007fefe8d9000     C:\windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x000007fef4df0000 - 0x000007fef4e55000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\runtime\win64\mclmcrrt7_16.dll
0x0000000077890000 - 0x0000000077897000     C:\windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x000007fefd940000 - 0x000007fefda17000     C:\windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x0000000075a20000 - 0x0000000075ad5000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\libmx.dll
0x0000000180000000 - 0x000000018000b000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\libmwresource_core.dll
0x00000000758a0000 - 0x0000000075944000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\libmwi18n.dll
0x000000007a170000 - 0x000000007a19c000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\boost_filesystem-vc90-mt-1_44.dll
0x000000007a560000 - 0x000000007a569000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\boost_system-vc90-mt-1_44.dll
0x000000007a010000 - 0x000000007a035000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\LIBEXPAT.dll
0x00000000605e0000 - 0x00000000607d1000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\icuin44.dll
0x000000005f970000 - 0x000000005fae1000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\icuuc44.dll
0x0000000010000000 - 0x0000000010e41000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\icudt44.dll
0x0000000074460000 - 0x0000000074563000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\libut.dll
0x0000000073f70000 - 0x00000000740b5000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\libmwfl.dll
0x000000007a350000 - 0x000000007a556000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\libmwMATLAB_res.dll
0x0000000000510000 - 0x0000000000520000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\boost_date_time-vc90-mt-1_44.dll
0x000000007a250000 - 0x000000007a263000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\boost_signals-vc90-mt-1_44.dll
0x000000007a2d0000 - 0x000000007a2e2000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\boost_thread-vc90-mt-1_44.dll
0x0000000000560000 - 0x00000000005a6000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\tbb.dll
0x000007fefd920000 - 0x000007fefd939000     C:\windows\system32\imagehlp.dll
0x000000006b640000 - 0x000000006b653000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\icuio44.dll
0x000007fef88e0000 - 0x000007fef8a05000     C:\windows\system32\dbghelp.dll
0x000000007a210000 - 0x000000007a228000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\zlib1.dll
0x0000000076100000 - 0x0000000076158000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\libmat.dll
0x0000000072d30000 - 0x0000000072f44000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\hdf5dll.dll
0x0000000002bd0000 - 0x0000000002e33000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\mclmcr.dll
0x0000000074970000 - 0x0000000074a41000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\mcr.dll
0x0000000075000000 - 0x0000000075324000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\iqm.dll
0x000000007bed0000 - 0x000000007c148000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\libmwservices.dll
0x0000000074330000 - 0x0000000074453000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\libmwmathutil.dll
0x0000000075f10000 - 0x0000000075f5d000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\mpath.dll
0x000000007b680000 - 0x000000007bb4d000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\mlutil.dll
0x000000006b5c0000 - 0x000000006b63f000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\xmlcore.dll
0x000000007bc30000 - 0x000000007be83000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\xerces-c_2_7.dll
0x000007fefed70000 - 0x000007fefedbd000     C:\windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x000007feff420000 - 0x000007feff428000     C:\windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x0000000002530000 - 0x0000000002546000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\libmwsettings_res.dll
0x0000000002560000 - 0x00000000025a7000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\boost_serialization-vc90-mt-1_44.dll
0x000007fef9610000 - 0x000007fef96b0000     C:\windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.18201_none_a4d3b9377117c3df\COMCTL32.dll
0x000007fefeb70000 - 0x000007fefec07000     C:\windows\system32\COMDLG32.dll
0x000007fefb430000 - 0x000007fefb446000     C:\windows\system32\NETAPI32.dll
0x000007fefb420000 - 0x000007fefb42c000     C:\windows\system32\netutils.dll
0x000007fefd090000 - 0x000007fefd0b3000     C:\windows\system32\srvcli.dll
0x000007fefb400000 - 0x000007fefb415000     C:\windows\system32\wkscli.dll
0x0000000056280000 - 0x0000000056a50000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll
0x000000006fd60000 - 0x000000006fd75000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\libmex.dll
0x0000000060530000 - 0x00000000605de000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll
0x0000000074880000 - 0x000000007496d000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\boost_regex-vc90-mt-1_44.dll
0x0000000060370000 - 0x00000000603f4000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\profiler.dll
0x0000000079f40000 - 0x0000000079f73000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\libmwmathrng.dll
0x0000000074c10000 - 0x0000000074cea000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\libmwmathcore.dll
0x0000000076160000 - 0x00000000761cb000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\libmwspmatrix.dll
0x0000000075ea0000 - 0x0000000075f02000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\libmwcholmod.dll
0x0000000002e90000 - 0x0000000002e9d000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\libmwamd.dll
0x0000000002eb0000 - 0x0000000002ebc000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\libmwcolamd.dll
0x000000006da20000 - 0x000000006da39000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\libmwblas.dll
0x000000006b5a0000 - 0x000000006b5b2000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\libmwbinder.dll
0x000000006da10000 - 0x000000006da1b000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\libmwompwrapper.dll
0x000000005f8e0000 - 0x000000005f962000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\libmwlapack.dll
0x0000000069cb0000 - 0x0000000069cd1000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\m_pcodeio.dll
0x0000000079b10000 - 0x0000000079b77000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\m_ir.dll
0x0000000056be0000 - 0x0000000057220000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\m_parser.dll
0x000000006b860000 - 0x000000006b87a000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\ir_xfmr.dll
0x00000000578c0000 - 0x0000000057b45000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\mcos.dll
0x000000006d9f0000 - 0x000000006d9fc000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\mtok.dll
0x00000000604f0000 - 0x0000000060521000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\m_pcodegen.dll
0x0000000079fb0000 - 0x0000000079fe5000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\libmwbridge.dll
0x000000005f4f0000 - 0x000000005f5b8000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\udd.dll
0x000000005f150000 - 0x000000005f297000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\libmwgui.dll
0x000000006b580000 - 0x000000006b597000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\graphics_util.dll
0x0000000002fc0000 - 0x0000000003970000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\hg.dll
0x0000000075710000 - 0x000000007579d000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\jmi.dll
0x0000000003990000 - 0x000000000399e000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\nativejava_services.dll
0x000000005f890000 - 0x000000005f8d3000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\libmwhardcopy.dll
0x000000005f0e0000 - 0x000000005f143000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\libuij.dll
0x000000005d7c0000 - 0x000000005d9c7000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\hgdatatypes.dll
0x000000005d6c0000 - 0x000000005d7b9000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\hgutils.dll
0x000000005b750000 - 0x000000005b80d000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\udd_mi.dll
0x0000000003a00000 - 0x0000000003cc9000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\uiw.dll
0x000000005fb10000 - 0x000000005fb1f000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\uinone.dll
0x0000000059b30000 - 0x000000005a014000     C:\windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_044aad0bab1eb146\mfc90.dll
0x000007fef7a20000 - 0x000007fef7a27000     C:\windows\system32\MSIMG32.dll
0x000000005f860000 - 0x000000005f881000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\mwoles05.DLL
0x000000005f060000 - 0x000000005f0d5000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\comcli.dll
0x00000000709b0000 - 0x00000000709df000     C:\windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.atl_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_0a1fd3a3a768b895\ATL90.DLL
0x000000005f6b0000 - 0x000000005f6bc000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\mlautoregister.dll
0x0000000003d20000 - 0x0000000003d30000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\boost_iostreams-vc90-mt-1_44.dll
0x000007fef5360000 - 0x000007fef53a0000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\ctfarchiver.dll
0x000007fef48a0000 - 0x000007fef48f0000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\dservices.dll
0x0000000003d60000 - 0x0000000003d89000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\libmwMCR_res.dll
0x0000000003da0000 - 0x0000000003da9000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\mcli18nutil.dll
0x000007fefaaa0000 - 0x000007fefaab8000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\ctfrt.dll
0x000007feeee60000 - 0x000007feeeefa000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\ctfrtcrypto.dll
0x0000000003de0000 - 0x0000000003e0d000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\xsd_binder.dll
0x000007fef6a40000 - 0x000007fef6a5f000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\jproxy.dll
0x000007feeeb80000 - 0x000007feeebe5000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\mclbase.dll
0x0000000003e40000 - 0x0000000003f92000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64\mvm.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xss512k -XX:PermSize=32m -Xms64m -XX:NewRatio=3 -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Xmx196m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=2147400000 -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -Dsun.awt.nopixfmt=true -Xshare:off -Xrs -Dsun.awt.disableMixing=true -Djava.library.path=C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v716\bin\win64 vfprintf abort 
java_command: <unknown>
Launcher Type: generic

Environment Variables:
USERNAME=Alby
ARCH=w32
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 Build 7600 

CPU:total 8 (8 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 42 stepping 7, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, ht

Memory: 4k page, physical 8331120k(2154712k free), swap 16000656k(8644612k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (14.3-b01) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.6.0_17-b04), built on Oct 11 2009 00:46:08 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 8.0

time: Thu Oct 23 13:15:12 2014
elapsed time: 0 seconds
```

Comment: do you have the original source for the copmiled application? Reading the solution you linked to, here is something to try; compile the standalone program against, but this time do it from [a new MATLAB profile](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/removing-user-preferences-from-deployed-apps). The reason is that compiled applications copy all those XML files in your preferences folder and bundle them with the compiled application... So if something in those files was caused the crash, this should solve it.